# React side panel transforming is not happening

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have created a custom sidepanel that pops up from the right side and closed on click of outside of the panel. The transition effect when opened and closed is not happening. Can someone help me with this? Help will be really apppreciated

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SlideDrawer from "./SlideDrawer.jsx";

function App() {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      {drawerOpen ? (
        <SlideDrawer show={drawerOpen} {...{ setDrawerOpen }} />
      ) : null}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen);
        }}
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slider-demo-bpi83t?file=/src/index.js:0-558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now, here are the snippets of your components and below a proper explanations of why it wasn't working.

**SlideDrawer.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./SlideDrawer.css";

export default function SlideDrawer({ setDrawerOpen, show }) {
  const sideMenuRef = useRef(null);

  const onOutsideClick = e => {
    if(sideMenuRef.current && !sideMenuRef.current.contains(e.target) && show) {
      setDrawerOpen(false)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", onOutsideClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", onOutsideClick);
  }, [show, sideMenuRef]);

  return (
    <div ref={sideMenuRef} className={`side-drawer ${show ? 'open' : ''}`}>
      <h1>Hello, I'm sliding!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SlideDrawer from "./SlideDrawer.jsx";

function App() {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <SlideDrawer show={drawerOpen} setDrawerOpen={setDrawerOpen} />
      <button
        onClick={() => setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen)}
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

#### Explanation

In `index.js` you were conditional rendering in this part:

```
{drawerOpen ? (
    <SlideDrawer show={drawerOpen} {...{ setDrawerOpen }} />
) : null}
```

So the component was being created every time that *drawerOpen* change.

This portion of code verifies if the click was done inside the drawer so you can close whenever it's outside.

```
const onOutsideClick = e => {
    if(sideMenuRef.current && !sideMenuRef.current.contains(e.target) && show) {
      setDrawerOpen(false)
    }
  }
```

#### Edit:

I change the **SlideDrawer** component using refs logic.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The query selector is intended to catch if the click is inside or outside your sidebar, you can change it to any classname you want, or select it the way you want.

Comment: Is there a much simpler way to achieve this side panel?

Comment: I think your approach is simpler enough and it gets the job done. Which part do you think you have to optimize?

Comment: Probably the queryselector, or may be some css?

Comment: I edited it so it's using React refs! @li97